# python imported module dot notation as function parameter input

Tags: python

New to python programming here. I need some help understand why this does not work:

```
import x.y # x is a package with __init__.py
def func1(x.y.z): # I get a syntax error here
```

It works when I do this:

```
import x.y
a = x.y.z
def func1(a):
```

I've search the web and can't find anything that would answer this somewhat directly.

Thanks.

Comment: What meaning would `x.y.z` have in the function signature during function *definition*? When you do `def func1(a):` it defines a function with one argument called `a`, i.e. the value of `a` in preceding code isn't even considered.

Comment: @vaultah I think OP means , why when I assign imported thing to a variable and use it as a function arguments , it's work correctly, but when I use it directly as a function argument I have a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `def` you define new functions which accept some *possibly unknown*(!) arguments.

So, `def sin(x):` means "define a function called `sin` that accepts one argument". Note that this code means that `x` can be *absolutely anything*, the function *definition* doesn't (and cannot) apply any restrictions on its type, value, size, etc.

When you do

```
a = "hello"
def test(a):
    pass
```

The `a` in the function definition is *merely an argument* that doesn't have *any* relation to any other `a` you use in your code! You could've called it `x`, `pi`, `z` or whatever as *the name doesn't really matter* (code readability aside).

When you try to write

```
def test(x.y.z):
    pass
```

You get a syntax error as *there exist restrictions on the variables' and arguments' names* that don't allow you to call a variable any name you want. Why? Simply because otherwise you'll get a lot of uncertainty. For example, how to parse this:

```
# a poorly formatted number literal or a variable definition??
1234hello = "test" 

# attempt to access a member of a class (or module) or a variable definition??
x.y.z = 5

# is "yay a variable's name or a poorly formatted string literal??
x = "yay - 5 

# the same question as above
f' = df/dx
```

A function argument is a variable, so the very same restrictions are imposed on it as well.

BTW, take a look at the SO code highlighter going nuts trying to highlight the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's making sense for me now.